# DataGridTextColumn binding to different DataContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I need to bind a DataGridTextColumn to a different DataContext, I know this is possible as  I am doing this correctly in a DaatGridComboBox. the code I have at the moment is

```
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" binding={wont work in here as this element is bounded to the itemsource of the DataGrid} IsReadOnly="True" Width="150">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" 
                        Value="{Binding DataContext.CustomerCollection.Name}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>         
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

What I have done wrong?

---- On bindingProxy --

I have setup the BindingProxy class how it is in the article. And have this

```
       <DataGrid.Resources>
            <l:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" 
                        Value="{Binding Data.Name, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

However, why would it know the element "Name"?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BindingProxy](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/), you can bind to data when the DataContext is not inherited

Comment: Thanks, can you see my edit above and see if you know how to answer my question on this subject? thanks

Comment: Name is the property binded in the BindingProxy.